# How do I overcome 'unicodeescape' in constructing HEX string to INT conversion in Python?

Tags: python, string, escaping

The challenge is to take a hex value in string format `"FF"` and convert it to its decimal equivalent.

I know that using the string format `"\xFF"`, this is as easy as `ord("\xFF")`.

However, I would like to parse a string of hex without the \x tag, i.e. `"01 02 03 04"`.

My approach has been to try to format the later string in the `"\xFF"` format, doing something like:

```
input = "01 02 03 04"
s = ""
s += "\x" + input[0:2]
```

However, any attempt to put the `"\"`, `"\x"`, or even `"\x0"` character into a string, I get the following error:

> SyntaxError: (unicode error) 'unicodeescape' codec can't decode bytes
>   in position 0-1: truncated \xXX escape

Since strings are immutable, I cannot create a string with the full "\xFF" format and then change the values after the fact.  Does anyone have a tip to get past this?

Thanks in advance... I hope what I'm asking makes sense!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `int` constructor takes an optional second argument giving its base, and will parse hex string representations if you tell it to use base 16:

```
input = "01 02 03 04"
s = input[0:2]
>>> int(s, 16)
1
>>> int('FF', 16)
255
```

Comment: why wouldnt you just do `int("FF",16)` ? whats the prepend business about?

Comment: Ahh!  I didn't realize 'int' had this ability!  Thank you both for helping me past this hurdle.  This is exactly what I was looking for.  Big thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you dont

```
my_input = "01 02 03 04"
s +=chr(int(my_input[0:2],16)) #results in "\x01" (note the 16 makes it hex chars)
```

as an aside dont use input as a variable name

what I think you actually want is

```
s = "".join(chr(int(c,16)) for c in "01 02 03 04".split())
#s is now "\x01\x02\x03\x04"
#or maybe
s = [int(c,16) for c in "01 02 03 04 0a".split()]
#s is now [1,2,3,4,10]
```

Comment: These are great solutions.  I am a novice in Python, so these answers help greatly!  Thank you for your time,